# Kafka MQTT sink can't forward to different topics

Tags: python, apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to send MQTT messages to different topics using Kafka. 
I'm using Confluent MqttSinkConnector and my connector config looks like this

```
{
"name" : "mqttSinkConnector",
"config" : {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "mqtt.server.uri": "tcp://mqttServer:1883",
    "topics":"mqttSink",
    "mqtt.qos": "1",
    "mqtt.username": "user",
    "mqtt.password": "pass",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "kafkaServer:9092",
    "confluent.topic.replication.factor": "1"
}}
```

I'm sending test messages to "mqttSink" topic of Kafka with different keys but they all end up in the "mqttSink" topic at the Mqtt broker. As i understood it should have landed in the "/t1" topic. Is there any way to publish to different Mqtt topics from within Kafka.

Test producers that i've tried;

```
# python confluent-kafka producer
p.produce('mqttSink', value=testStr, key=b'/t1')
# python kafka producer
producer.send("mqttSink",key=b'/t1', value=testStr).get(timeout=30)
```

Comment: First MQTT topics really shouldn't start with a leading `/` (while the spec allows it, it breaks things like shared subscriptions), secondly why is the key value a byte (leading `b`) array not a string?

Comment: When I receive messages from am MQTT source the keys show up as arrays so I've tried with both arrays and strings without any luck.

Comment: You're using StringConverter, but sending data as python raw `bytes` objects. Not sure if that matters, but you might want to put an `encode` function call for UTF-8